# PHP Preg-replace - Identify only dashes, spaces and breaks

Tags: php, preg-replace

Good morning, I have a string in which there are breaks represented as `<p>----</p>`. The number of dash is often different. Sometimes there are 4, sometimes 5, etc.

Something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum 
<p>------</p>
Lorem Ipsum 
<p>----------------</p>
Lorem Ipsum 
<p>--------------</p>
```

I would like to write a php preg_replace command to make them all uniform and identical.

This is what I developed, but it doesn't work. Where is the error?

```
$search = "/(<p>-)(.*?)(-<\/p>)/";
$replace = "<p>-------------</p>";
$item = preg_replace($search,$replace,$item);
```

Moreover there is something more precise rather than `(.*?)` to match only spaces and dashes.

**EDIT 1:**
Thanks to the team in the answer section, I correct the function like this:

```
$search = "/(<p>-)[\h-]+(<\/p>)/";
$replace = "<p>-------------</p>";
$item = preg_replace($search,$replace,$item);
```

This works fine as long as long the text doesn't have a break between the last dash and `</p>`. How can I identify the dashed, spaces and also capture the `\n`?

Example:
`<p>----- \n</p>`

Comment: You can match only spaces and dashes with `[\h-]+`

Comment: Note: when you're writing a question, make sure you post an example which fits the description. You say your code doesn't work, but it works just fine on the example from the question: https://3v4l.org/6mLIA

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need the 3 capture groups. You can match  zero or more horizontal whitspace chars using `[\h-]*` and replace that with the fixed replacement of `<p>-------------</p>`

Example, where as in your code there is always a `-` at the start and end:

```
$item = <<<DATA
Lorem ipsum 
<p>------</p>
Lorem Ipsum 
<p>----------------</p>
Lorem Ipsum 
<p>---------   -----</p>
DATA;

$search = "~<p>-[\h-]*-</p>~";
$replace = "<p>-------------</p>";
$item = preg_replace($search, $replace, $item);

echo $item;
```

Output

```
Lorem ipsum 
<p>-------------</p>
Lorem Ipsum 
<p>-------------</p>
Lorem Ipsum 
<p>-------------</p>
```

Comment: Your question strikes me as a little unclear with that `\n`.  Is this how you're trying to explain a newline character or do you _actually_ have a slash followed by an `n` in the line?  If you are just trying to match an invisible newline, then change TheFourthBird's pattern fro `\h` to `\s` and you're done.

Comment: @Andreito If you also want to match newline characters, you can use `\s` like `$search = "~<p>-[\s-]*-</p>~";`

Answer (score 0):

You may try finding the pattern `<p>-{1,}</p>` and then replace with however many dashes you want, e.g. `<p>-----</p>`:

```php
$input = "Lorem ipsum \n<p>------</p>\nLorem Ipsum \n<p>----------------</p>\nLorem Ipsum\n<p>--------------</p>";
$output = preg_replace("/<p>\s*-{1,}\s*<\/p>/", "<p>-----</p>", $input);
echo $output;
```

This prints:

```
Lorem ipsum 
<p>-----</p>
Lorem Ipsum 
<p>-----</p>
Lorem Ipsum
<p>-----</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to identify only the dash (and not the dashes and the spaces). So when there is a ''"<p>------ </p>", the preg_replace does not catch the break. How can I correct it?

Comment: @Andreito Then try using the regex pattern `<p>\s*-{1,}\s*<\/p>`, which allows for optional whitespace on either end of the inside of the `<p>` tags.

Comment: I tried to use this ```/(<p>-)[\h-]+(<\/p>)/``` and seems to work fine. BUT if there is a break between the last dash and </p>, it does not work. How can I identify the dashed, spaces and even catch the \n ?

Comment: Please **edit** your question and reveal the actual problem to us.  Thanks.

Comment: Done. Thanks Tim!

Comment: and of course `{1,}` is more simply expressed as `+`.